# List of .NET libraries, classes, methods, etc, which are not supported by MONO?

Tags: .net, mono

I want to make my application to run on MAC machine, for that I want to know .NET libraries, classes, methods, etc, which are not supported by MONO.
I am searching for this and I got lot of information from the sites

1. [http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX)
2. http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA
3. [http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications)
4. http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility
5. http://monodevelop.com/
6. http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

If you have more information, please tell me...

Comment: *but used in visual studio* Wrong. This question would be like "how can I run Visual Studio without installing .NET but installing Mono"? You should ask "which are not supported by MONO but present in .NET version xxx" (and specify the version!)

Comment: @xanatos: updated the question addressing your good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the [Mono Class Status Pages](http://go-mono.com/status/) to see things that Mono doesn't yet support or things that they have added. Here's the [status of the `System.Web` namespace](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System.Web), for example.

Comment: Thanks friism, This is the list which i want